# Which tense should I use, past tense or present perfect?

Tags: tense

Scenario
I m having coffee with my girlfriend.

She says " Nice coffee"

Its present tense, so what should I say?

1. Thanks, I made it.
2. Thanks, I have made it.
3. Thanks, I make it.

Is past tense used for action completed in the past, some time back, yesterday, last week etc. Or this can be used for completed actions also in present tense ?
How to say present completed action?
L

Comment: 1 & 2 are fine. Whichever you prefer. 3 doesn't work in this context.

Comment: "Nice coffee" doesn't really have a "tense".

Answer (score 0):

"Nice coffee" doesn't contain a verb, so it's not present tense. If we imagine she said "This is very nice coffee", alright  .  "Is" = present tense.

Next, you may respond:

> 1. Thanks, I made it.

Correct. This is the best choice. You made the coffee, and it's done.

> 2. Thanks, I have made it.

Not really a good choice. Present perfect ties the past to the present, and is especially applicable when you continue the sentence in the present, and on into the future:  "I **have made** the cookie dough, now we need to turn on the oven and bake the cookies for 10 minutes."  Or, "I **have made** the coffee, and now we can enjoy it out on the veranda."

However, you are much less likely to use the present perfect, and then *stop*. So you would usually not say "I have made it."  (followed by silence)

> 3. Thanks, I make it.

In English, the most standard present tense is actually the present continuous. Here though, you are using the simple present.  The simple present is often used to indicate repeated actions. So, if you said "Thanks, I make it with this high tech espresso machine, and it turns out great", you mean "I often, usually make it with the espresso machine", and it would be a reasonable response to your girlfriend.

Simply saying "I make it" in this context, doesn't fit. Because you are probably trying to say that you made it "this one time", "the coffee we are drinking now". But the simple present doesn't mean that. It means "usually", "often", "in general".

> How to say present completed action?

The simple past tense, such as "I made the coffee".

Comment: Might be worth adding that the second sentence might confusing in other contexts because **make it** has a special meaning (to succeed)..

Comment: @JavaLatte , sure. The word "make" has more than 50 definitions. "I made it" can mean "I finally arrived".